How to manage a simple <dialog> modal pop up?
I want to manage a modal pop up on page load using a <dialog> tag and the showModal() method. But I can't figure out the right & simple way to do it. After some forum research, I finally sorted out a script to open it. But now I'm stuck when trying to close it.
My HTML element is pretty basic :
<dialog id="myDialog">
    <p>Message</p>
    <button id="btnClose">OK</button>
</dialog>

Then there's my current script:
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal() { 
          document.getElementById("myDialog").showModal(); 
    } 

    function closeModal() { 
          document.getElementById("myDialog").close(); 
    }
 
    window.onload = function() {
           openModal();
    };

    document.getElementById("btnClose").addEventListener("click", closeModal);

</script>

Problem seems to be on the last line: I keep having the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')".
I found a workaround and manage to close the modal if I call the closeModal() function directly from the button tag:
<button id="btnClose" onclick="closeModal()">OK</button>
But I really don't understand why this works and not when I try to listen to the button click in the script ?

 "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" means that it can't find the element with id="btnClose", I would assume because the html hasn't loaded yet. Do similarly lto your openModal() function, and add your event listener within the window.onload.

may depending where your script position is on your page....

thanks for your feedbacks! I found my answer right after posting the question - when I finally thought of googling the error message rather than "modal not working"(that's how dumb I am...). It was indeed linked to the script executing before everything was loaded. I'm learning :) ! Now I'm on a new quest: finding out why this modal works fine on desktop but not on mobile browsers...
